# Has Superman ever escaped a black hole?

Tags: dc, superman, space, speed-of-light

Reading a [DC wiki](http://dccinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Kryptonian) (yes, wikipedias are bad...), it mentions in the Super Speed section for Kryptonians that Superman can travel at the speed of light or faster than light when in space.

I'm guessing there's been a few fights out there in the Milky Way and beyond, has Superman ever been close enough to a black hole in which he had to escape from?

I'm looking for any version of Superman from any Universe as I think, if this had ever occured, then it probably didn't happen often.

Comment: pardon me while I express my physics pedantry, which admittedly has nothing to do with the right answer, but going faster than the speed of light *is not* going to get you out of a black hole. The escape velocity is not the problem; the problem is that space/time inside the event horizon is so warped that there is simply no direction you can move forward that doesn't go towards the singularity. The faster you try to move out of the black hole the faster you end up at it's center. Rant over, please carry on.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - Always useful to know how comic book physics compares with real-life physics. Your rant is much appreciated =)

Comment: Not even he could escape. He would be spaghettified by intense tidal forces before he even got close to the event horizon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Yes, Pre-Crisis Superman (one of the strongest versions of the character in all of the DC continuities) has indeed been fast enough to escape the gravitational pull of a black hole by moving faster than light.

- Different depictions of the character show Superman being able to reach the speed of light, cross the temporal barriers preventing travel to the future or the past, and some have even allowed him the ability to escape singularities, with some degree of difficulty. Suffice it to say, this ability is dependent strictly on the plot of the writer, the permission of the editor and the suspension of belief on the part of the readers.
- In a Pre-Crisis depiction, he is shown here being fast enough to escape our conception of the UNIVERSE and moving beyond the very fabric of what we call existence.

[image]

[image]

- In other Pre-Crisis depictions he was shown to be able to transcend time itself by flying faster than the speed of light and travel to the distant future.

[image]

[image]

- And for you sticklers who might say these depictions of super-speed are not an indication of his ability to escape singularities (black holes), here he is escaping a weaponized black hole and collapsing it by throwing a spaceship into it.
- He escapes it by simply being able to fly faster than its event horizon was capable of holding him. (This means to me, he must not have crossed the true event horizon because physics says, nothing can return from that boundary...not even light!)

[image]

Comment: So, he *could* escape from a black hole. But *has* he ever?

Comment: I've got to agree with @ksmarts on this one. It's clear that he can (theoretically) but your answer doesn't actually answer the question asked. Reluctantly downvoted.

Comment: Patience IS a virtue. And the ability to travel fast enough to transcend light means he could easily escape a black hole since the physics say not even light, the fastest thing in our understanding cannot.

Comment: Assuming of course, the speed barriers of time and "infinity" can escape a black hole? This answer is better answered by removing everything else except the last one.

Comment: @Thaddeus So you expect a comic book to obey physics in the same edit that you show someone from that comic book "plugging" a black hole by throwing things into it?

Comment: I don't expect anything at all. Since I do science for a living, I understand this is all ENTERTAINMENT. I recognize the physics involved would be far more incredible if people understood what they are, I am simply trying to present the idea the character has been vastly more powerful than mere physics can contain and escaping the very fabric of the universe, includes the ability to escape singularities which would be contained within the universe the character just transcended...

Comment: Light cannot escape a black hole. Superman can go faster than light. This does not necessarily mean that Superman can escape a black hole.

Comment: I didn't write the comics. Why all the fan boy rage directed at me? I am presented the character as DC COMICS has allowed him to be depicted. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: FWIW: If Superman can go faster than "the bonds of infinity", he probably *can* escape a black hole - my issue is solely with the "If-Then" logic of "faster than light = able to escape a black hole"

Comment: If we use math to determine that the speed of light is the limit to how fast something can go in our universe, but an object SOMEHOW does go faster than light, then the mathematics to determine how fast that is are able to be calculated. Is the ability to escape a black hole +10% the speed of light? +20%? We don't know. But if he can go faster than whatever (n) value is, then he is traveling faster than the speed of light + (n). If-then may feel wrong but mathematically speaking it is a simplification but essentially correct.

Comment: Your answer seems to contradict itself. If he'd not crossed the event horizon, he's not actually escaping from the black hole

Comment: Using the laws of physics as we understand them, NOTHING can escape the event horizon. USING COMICS PHYSICS which transcend the KNOWN LAWS OF PHYSICS, Superman IS able to cross the event horizon and escape a singularity. I DID NOT WRITE THE COMIC. I found a depiction that met the requirements and then showed the character has indeed been even FASTER than that. Millions of times faster, also depicted. Does the answer contradict itself? Yes, because it is reconciling ENTERTAINMENT PHYSICS with real physics. It almost never works. That's entertainment, folks.

Comment: @Thaddeus ... While I don't know the mathematics behind the physics, I understand what you are saying and agree. Your argument is compelling to me. And yes, that's entertainment. +1 for a well put together answer.

Comment: For those wondering why "speed doesn't matter" in escaping a black hole: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8477/why-cant-light-escape-from-a-classical-black-hole?rq=1

Comment: (None of which changes the fact that this is clearly the right answer because it has screen shots. Sadly, it lacks freehand circles, but noone's perfect.)

Comment: One of the Post-Crisis depictions which I did not include actually cites a similar perspective and Superman was forced to accept the help of a similarly trapped alien to make the jump past the event horizon. It appeared later writers knew this fact Michael.

Comment: @Thaddeus hopefully they also knew that black holes don't look like little whirlpools in space :) if Superman's feet were that close to the black hole in that one panel, as a sphere his feet would *definitely* be inside the event horizon. Plus, a "miniature" black hole should be no big deal -- it'll evaporate before it can do any harm. These people need to read more Hawking.

Comment: The later depiction (which was weird, I may include it as a contrast) showed him trapped within what appeared to be a very large black hole or holes, large event horizon (not sure if there was one or two, rumor has it they were a pair of orbiting black holes). He needed the ability of an alien to tear ruptures in space time so they could force a way back to normal space where a direction did not lead toward the middle of the singularity. It was indeed different than previous depictions.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield These writers appear to think that you can "plug" a black hole, presumably stopping its gravitational effect, by *adding* matter to it. They need to read *a lot* more. I have no idea how that's supposed to work, even with comic-book physics.

Comment: @Thaddeus - Firstly, thank you for your brilliant answer! I am well aware on how **not** to compare comic book physics with real-life physics as there's plenty of discrepancies. Secondly, apologies for putting you in the middle of "War of the Geeks" as your answer certainly deserves to be upvoted (I believe posts that are clearly explained, provide evidence and are close enough to answering questions should receive positive attention).

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't track down the exact right page but after the fairly recent Superman: Doomed Superman pushed Braniac into a black hole and emerged.

From Action Comics issue 35:
[image: Action Comics 35]

Comment: Awesome, cheers for this!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Pre Crisis Superman closes black hole]

Escape?  He has closed one with his bare hands and sheer power.