# Can the Flash run fast enough to escape a black hole?

Tags: dc, the-flash

In [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117886/what-is-the-flashs-normal-or-jogging-speed) question, the answer explores the calculated and proposed speeds that the flash can run/jog at.

In [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5928/can-the-flash-run-faster-than-light) question, it was determined the Flash could run faster than the speed of light. To me these beg a single question.

**Can the Flash run fast enough to escape a black hole?**

EDIT: Assume the black hole is "sucking" a massive asteroid belt, and the flash is "running and jumping" from asteroid to asteroid.

EDIT2: I found a link [here](http://www.comicbloc.com/forums/showthread.php?s=6afd74628e8037dbb34b4777aeca66e7&t=34745&page=2) where it is mentioned the Flash can step on single molecules. Even without the asteroids, let's assume this is true (as there's things flying into the black hole for him to "step?" on). This may not be canon, but it's been seen by multiple people, so maybe there is canon somewhere?

Comment: Shouldn't that depend on the distance to the black hole?

Comment: Superman can fly fast enough -- http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80794/has-superman-ever-escaped-a-black-hole  Flash has two problems, I guess: (i) he needs some kind of surface to run on -- which you have now addressed in your question --, (ii) tidal forces. - http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/fall_in.html

Comment: If this has or were to come up in the comics, the answer is, whatever the writers decide. As a thought exercise, it breaks down with the impossibility of The Flash's powers.

Comment: https://m.reddit.com/r/whowouldwin/comments/3cnhsk/could_the_flash_escape_a_black_hole/  If you're asking, from a physics standpoint, could he run fast enough to escape a black hole's event horizon, assuming somehow he could actually run as fast as depicted in comics, the answer is "no", but from an in comics universe standpoint, "probably yes."

Comment: @Kai I understand the Physics standpoint about there being no "out" of a black hole, but if you've read some of the Pre-Crisis Superman (like in the link in the comment above, it says that Superman literally breaks time and space, and therefore there would be an "out" to the black hole, albeit a "out of reality/space/time/time space continuum" thing.

Comment: @Anoplexian As I said, in the in comics universe standpoint, "probably yes."

Comment: I'd guess he could, if it's a supermassive black hole. A small black hole would tear him and everything around him apart before he even reached its event horizon, so he would never get to test whether or not he could escape it. A supermassive black hole, on the other hand, has a more evenly distributed tidal force, and may allow him to pass its event horizon with little damage. At which point, if the Flash can travel faster than light, he could possibly get back out.

Comment: Also, just pointing it out, it is not possible to travel at or above the speed of light (unless you are light, in which case, you’d be traveling at exactly the speed of light).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes?

**In the Arrowverse** Flash. A black hole forms over Central City and the Flash is able to run in the opposite direction to collapse it (with the assistance of FireStorm).

**In the DCAU:**

When Flash faces Brainiac/Luther, he runs so fast he is kind of gets absorbed by the Speed Force. He states that he can't ever go that fast again, or he might not come back. - JLU "Divided We Fall"

Another time, Flash, with the help of Green Lantern, is able to run fast enough to throw some kind of generator to open a worm hole which is threatening the sun. Which is kind of like outrunning a blackhole, except he is running towards it... - JLA "Eclipsed: Part 2"

Answer (score 1):

In " Flash The Human Race " i suppose The Flash runs from the edge of the universe ( Weird right ) back to earth. There he asks everyone on earth to run to gather enough kinetic energy. He asks the space gamblers that are putting the fastest beings in every planet. Flash tells them that he would race the space gamblers back to earth to save everybody's planet. They reply by saying that that is impossible because they can teleport. He races them and runs faster than any word in time can describe. Practically he defies time. A blackhole is so fast that not even light can escape, but the Flash surfaces that speed. In my opinion if the flash had a surface to run on he could.